# swap the words in a column using pyspark or pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe where I want to swap or reverse the order of words in a column per ID.

Input data:

```
+----------+-----+-------------+
| date     | ID  | words       |
+----------+-----+-------------+
| 09-01-20 | xyz | pixel pearl |
| 09-01-20 | xyz | place order |
| 09-01-20 | xyz | current pro |
| 09-01-20 | xyz | order place |
| 09-01-20 | abc | hello there |
| 09-01-20 | abc | there hello |
| 09-01-20 | abc | very good   |
| 09-01-20 | abc | order place |
```

Below is the desired result where the  'order place' has been reversed in 4th row. The 1st and 3rd rows remain unchanged since no reverse was present within the same ID 'xyz'. Then for ID 'abc' the order of words will change from 'there hello' to 'hello there', but will do nothing with 'order place'.

```
+----------+-----+-------------+
| date     | ID  | words       |
+----------+-----+-------------+
| 09-01-20 | xyz | pixel pearl |
| 09-01-20 | xyz | place order |
| 09-01-20 | xyz | current pro |
| 09-01-20 | xyz | place order |
| 09-01-20 | abc | hello there |
| 09-01-20 | abc | hello there |
| 09-01-20 | abc | very good   |
| 09-01-20 | abc | order place |
```

Thanks! and much appreciated!

Comment: Lets say a new phrase comes say "abcd wxyz" and then another phrase appears "wxyz abcd". How would you decide which one is in the right order and which one has to be reversed?

Comment: That's what I have been struggling that how to determine if the reverse is needed or not!

Comment: Well its more of a logic problem than a code problem in that case. Once you can figure out how you can identify the right ordered phrases and the wrong ordered phrases, its a simple apply function to fix it.

Comment: Could it be possible that when use apply call a function. In the function, use reverse() and see if the reverse is matching with any of the original words within same ID. If reverse is matching with original words then keep the reversed words if not matching then keep the original words.

Comment: See thats my question to you. How do you identify 'original'? i.e. Which one of this is original "xyz abc" or "abc xyz". Doing this reversal is not a big problem after that.

Comment: which ever comes first that can be used as original. For example, if 'abc xyz' comes first and 'xyz abc' comes later then the reverse the later one to 'abc xyz'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas try this:

```
df['words'] = df.groupby(df['words'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(set(x.split(' ')))))['words']\
  .transform('first')
```

Output:

```
       date   ID        words
0  09-01-20  xyz  pixel pearl
1  09-01-20  xyz  place order
2  09-01-20  xyz  current pro
3  09-01-20  xyz  place order
4  09-01-20  abc  hello there
5  09-01-20  abc  hello there
6  09-01-20  abc    very good
7  09-01-20  abc  place order
```

Details, first create groups using split and set to get like words together no matter the order.   Then, in each group, transform the value in 'words' to get the first occurrence of 'words'.

Comment: Awesome!!! Fantastic! I got the desired results. I had some idea what you used except didn't think about 'set' and not sure how to do transform. Can you please elaborate how transform works in this case?

Comment: Sure. groupby transform returns a results with the same rows as your original dataframe, you are transforming the 'words' column and change the result to something else, in this case, you are getting the first value in words and letting all subsequent values in each group equal to the first value.